# How to make javascript variable global in phoneGap api

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning how to use phonegap now and learning is going great but I'm stuck with global variable in phoneGap Api. Actually First I'm getting the result from xml file and then insert the data into Database. I have done this work but now I want to get the last id of inserted row and then insert into another table because in xml there are sub nodes.

```
function populateDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fruit');
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fruit_benefit');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fruit (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, fname,fsname,fruit_icon,fruit_image)');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fruit_benefit (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, benefit, fruit_id)');
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('fruit').each(function(){
                var fname = $(this).find('fname').text();
                var fsname = $(this).find('fsname').text();
                var fruit_icon = $(this).find('fruit_icon').text();
                var fruit_image = $(this).find('fruit_image').text();
                //$('<div class="items" id="link_'+fname+'"></div>').html('<a href="'+fsname+'">'+fname+'</a>').appendTo('#lbUsers');
                db.transaction(function(transaction) { 
                    transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO fruit (fname,fsname,fruit_icon,fruit_image) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',[fname, fsname, fruit_icon, fruit_image],function(transaction, results){
               var lastId = results.insertId; 
            },nullHandler,errorHandler);
              });

              alert(lastId);

            });
        }
    });

}
```

The relevant lines are:

```
var lastId = results.insertId; //The last inserted id is shown here.

alert(lastId); //I want to show last inserted id here
```

I have tried both a JavaScript global variable and local storage but neither are working.

Comment: This question would be better suited for StackOverflow. This site is for conceptual questions.

Answer (score -2):

You don't even need it to be global for this. Define the lastId in the function but before the foreach. If that doesn't work, then making it global should really work, by moving the var lastId; line before function populateDB()

```
function populateDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fruit');
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fruit_benefit');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fruit (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, fname,fsname,fruit_icon,fruit_image)');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fruit_benefit (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, benefit, fruit_id)');
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {

            var lastId;

            $(xml).find('fruit').each(function(){
                var fname = $(this).find('fname').text();
                var fsname = $(this).find('fsname').text();
                var fruit_icon = $(this).find('fruit_icon').text();
                var fruit_image = $(this).find('fruit_image').text();
                //$('<div class="items" id="link_'+fname+'"></div>').html('<a href="'+fsname+'">'+fname+'</a>').appendTo('#lbUsers');
                db.transaction(function(transaction) { 
                    transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO fruit (fname,fsname,fruit_icon,fruit_image) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',[fname, fsname, fruit_icon, fruit_image],function(transaction, results){
               lastId = results.insertId; 
            },nullHandler,errorHandler);
              });

              alert(lastId);

            });
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: You already answered under the duplicate, there is no need to also copy your answer here.